# AS2: How to iterate X times through a percentage calculation (containing a circular reference)?

Tags: excel, math, iteration, actionscript-2, circular-reference

Here is a question for the Excel / math-wizards.

I'm having trouble doing a calculation which is based on a formula with a circular reference. The calculation has been done in an Excel worksheet.

I've deducted the following equations from an Excel file:

a = 240000

b = 1400 + c + 850 + 2995

c = CEIL( ( a + b ) * 0.015, 100 )

After the iterations the total of A+B is supposed to be 249045 (where b = 9045).

In the Excel file this gives a circular reference, which is set to be allowed to iterate 4 times.

My problem: Recreate the calculation in AS2, going through 4 iterations.

I am not good enough at math to break this problem down.

Can anyone out there help me?

Edit: I've changed the formatting of the number in variable a. Sorry, I'm from DK and we use period as a thousand separator. I've removed it to avoid confusion :-)

2nd edit: The third equation, C uses Excels CEIL() function to round the number to nearest hundredth.

Comment: Could you give more details as to what you are trying to calculate? How do you know that the final value of b is 9045?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function calcRegistrationTax( amount, iterations ) {

    function roundToWhole( n, to ) {

        if( n > 0 )
            return Math.ceil( n/ to ) * to;
        else if( n < 0)
            return Math.floor( n/ to ) * to;
        else
            return to;
    }

    var a = amount;
    var b = 0;
    var c = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++){           
        b = basicCost + ( c ) + financeDeclaration + handlingFee;       
        c = ( a + b ) * basicFeeRatio;
        c = roundToWhole( c, 100 ); 
    }

    return b;
}

totalAmount = 240000 + calcRegistrationTax( 240000, 4 ); // This gives 249045
```

This did it, thanks to Benjamin for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know action script, but I think you want:

```
a = 240000
c = 0
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    b = 1400 + c + 850 + 2995
    c = (a + b) * 0.015
}
```

But you need to determine what to use for the initial value of c. I assume that Excel uses 0, since I get the same value when running the above as I get in Excel with iterations = 4, c = 3734.69...

Where do you get the "A + B is supposed to be 249045" value? In Excel and in the above AS, b only reaches 8979 with those values.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was a bit unprecise in my question. I've edited my original question to reflect the actual problem & solution, which I found, thanks to Benjamin.